# Ping causes high cpu when disconnected from network

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, ping, wininet

I'm making a C# Pinger in WPF using Ping() and BackgroundWorker(). Here is my full code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Pinger
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("wininet.dll")] private static extern bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

        public static bool IsConnectedToInternet() { return InternetGetConnectedState(out _, 0); }

        private readonly BackgroundWorker BackWork_Pinger = new BackgroundWorker();

        private int counter = 0; private readonly Ping pinger = new Ping();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BackWork_Pinger.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            BackWork_Pinger.DoWork += (_, args) => { for (int i = 1; i > 0; ++i) { if (IsConnectedToInternet()) { BackWork_Pinger.ReportProgress(i); Thread.Sleep(100); } } };

            BackWork_Pinger.ProgressChanged += (_, args) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    PingReply pingReply = pinger.Send("8.8.8.8");

                    if (pingReply != null)
                    {
                        switch (pingReply.Status)
                        {
                            case IPStatus.Success:

                                int PingNumber = Convert.ToInt32(pingReply.RoundtripTime);

                                if (PingNumber < 100) { Ping_Value.Foreground = Brushes.Lime; Ping_Value.Text = PingNumber + " ms"; }

                                else if (PingNumber < 300) { Ping_Value.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow; Ping_Value.Text = PingNumber + " ms"; }

                                else if (PingNumber < 500) { Ping_Value.Foreground = Brushes.DarkOrange; Ping_Value.Text = PingNumber + " ms"; }

                                else { Ping_Value.Foreground = Brushes.Red; Ping_Value.Text = "Bad"; }

                                break;

                            case IPStatus.TimedOut: Ping_Value.Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke; Ping_Value.Text = "Disconnected"; break;

                            default: Ping_Value.Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke; Ping_Value.Text = "Disconnected"; break;
                        }
                    }
                    else { Ping_Value.Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke; Ping_Value.Text = "Disconnected"; }
                }
                catch { Ping_Value.Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke; Ping_Value.Text = "Disconnected"; }

                Counter.Content = counter.ToString(); counter++;
            };

            BackWork_Pinger.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I wanna make a Pinger that works fine and not freezing my WinForm while disconnected or bad RoundTripTime. Is there any help to make a smooth pinger? or is there any demo project that i can modify from? Thank youuu :)

Comment: If `IsConnectedToInternet` returns false, you do not wait but immediately call it again.

Comment: try to rewrite your code completely, get rid of dll import and backgroundworker and use Task based async pattern with .NET `System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping` like awaiting `new Ping().SendPingAsync(IP)`

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to use the async Ping API correctly. Using the async API makes the backgroundthread to handle the ping obsolete.

Comment: I have fixed some typos to make it compile.

Comment: @Fildor It's WPF, exactly the MainWindow.xaml.cs file

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Ohhh thank you, i'll learn more about that

Comment: Ah, yes. Looked like WF, sorry. Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is your wrong implementation. You are misunderstanding the `Backgroundworker`. `Backgroundworker.DoWork` is executed on a background thread while `Backgroundworker.ProgressChanged` is executed on the main tread/UI thread. You are currently executing the long-running operation on the UI thread which results in freezing this thread. The solution is to execute the long-running operation in the `DoWork` handler.

You should use the modern Task library to implement the background task using `Task.Run` and report progress using the [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-6.0) class. This way you have a clean and modern async way to replace the old event based `Backgroundworker`.

In case of the `Ping` class you should know that it already exposes an asynchronous API which you should use.
Instead of `Ping.Send` call `Ping.SendPingAsync`. This way you don't need a background thread any more.
Also make use of the `PingOptions` and timeout to add more robustness to your application.

Notice that `Ping` implements `IDisposable`: you probably need to take care of the object lifetime and call `Dispose().`

Your improved cancelable version looks as followed:

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }
private Ping PingSender { get; }

private void OnCancelButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Abort
  this.CancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
}

public async Task StartPingTargetAsync(string hostNameOrIp)
{  
  IProgress<(IPStatus PingStatus, long PingDuration)> progressReporter = new Progress<(IPStatus PingStatus, long PingDuration)>(ShowProgress);
  this.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  CancellationToken cancellationToken = this.CancellationTokenSource.Token;

  try
  {  
    await PingIpAsync(hostNameOrIp, progressReporter, cancellationToken);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // Optional: clean up/roll back
  }
  finally
  {
    this.CancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
    this.CancellationTokenSource = null;
  }
}

private async Task PingIpAsync(
  string hostNameOrIp, 
  IProgress<(IPStatus PingStatus, long PingDuration)> progressReporter,
  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  while (true)
  {
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), cancellationToken);
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // Consider to use PingOptions and a time-out to add more robustness
    var options = new PingOptions (64, true);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    int timeoutInMilliseconds = (int) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;
    PingReply reply = await PingSender.SendPingAsync(hostNameOrIp, timeoutInMilliseconds, buffer, options);

    var progressData = (reply.Status, reply.RoundtripTime);
    progressReporter.Report(progressData);
  }
}

private void ShowProgress((IPStatus PingStatus, long PingDuration) progressData)
{
  Brush messageBrush = Brushes.WhiteSmoke;
  string message = $"{progressData.PingDuration} ms";

  switch (progressData.PingStatus)
  {
    case IPStatus.Success:
    {
      if (progressData.PingDuration < 100) 
      { 
        messageBrush = Brushes.Lime; 
      }
      else if (progressData.PingDuration < 300) 
      { 
        messageBrush = Brushes.Yellow; 
      } 
      else if (progressData.PingDuration < 500) 
      { 
        messageBrush = Brushes.DarkOrange; 
      }
      else 
      { 
        messageBrush = Brushes.Red; 
        message = "Bad"; 
      }
      break;
    }
    case IPStatus.TimedOut: 
      messageBrush = Brushes.WhiteSmoke; 
      message = "Disconnected"; 
      break;
  }

  Ping_Value.Foreground = messageBrush; 
  Ping_Value.Text = message; 
}
```

Comment: +1 for the modern way. Do you miss to declare `progressReporter`? Do you miss a pamareter in `PinIpAsync`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I also found that `Ping` is a .NET class that already offers an async API. I have fixed the code example accordingly.

Comment: @BionicCode How do i call it? I mean, can i call StartPingTargetAsync("www.google.com") in public MainWindow()? or is it in Main_Window_Loaded? Sorry for my less knowledge :(

Comment: Yes, you call it like `await StartPingTargetAsync("stackoverflow.com");`. You can then assign `OnCancelButtonClicked` to the `Button.Click` event to cancel or stop it from the UI.

Comment: Just a heads-up and assignment for the OP: `this.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();` will throw if the property is null. So, you may disable/enable the button, so that code will only have a chance of executing when the property is actually set, and/or you may make this null-Safe.

Comment: @Fildor Thank you. I have made it more robust by by invalidating the CancellationTokenSource property and by adding a null check to help the OP.

Comment: @JackySetiawan please check my updated version that adds robustness to handing the CancellationTokenSource property.

Comment: @BionicCode Thank you. I call `await StartPingTargetAsync("example.com")` on starter button event and there is an error occured **System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'**. Anyway, i added `async` to the button event because of `await`. Is there a solution? Sorry again...

Comment: Where do you get the exception? Don't forget to initialize the `PingSender` property in your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

BackgroundWorker call `DoWork` on parrale thread and callback `ProgressChanged` on UI thread. In your code, the ping is done on `ProgressChanged`, thus in the UI thread. When the UI thread work, the UI is freezed.

To avoid freezing the screen, it is necessary to execute the work on another thread. The ping must be in `DoWork` :

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BackWork_Pinger.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    BackWork_Pinger.DoWork += (_, args) =>
    {
        for (int i = 1; i > 0; ++i)
        {
            PingReply pingReply = null;
            if (IsConnectedToInternet())
            {
                try
                {
                    PingReply pingReply = pinger.Send("8.8.8.8");
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
            //Even if disconected
            //Report progress and pause
            BackWork_Pinger.ReportProgress(i, pingReply);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    };

    BackWork_Pinger.ProgressChanged += (_, args) =>
    {
        PingReply pingReply = pinger.Send("8.8.8.8");

        if (pingReply != null)
        {
            ...
        }
        else { Ping_Value.Foreground = Brushes.WhiteSmoke; Ping_Value.Text = "Disconnected"; } }
        Counter.Content = counter.ToString(); counter++;
    };

    // Start the work when the windows is loaded
    Loaded += (s, e) => { BackWork_Pinger.RunWorkerAsync(); };
    // Else, the work's ProgressChanged can update Ping_Value before it's intanciated
}
```

Comment: Also what's the intention behind the error-swallowing `try`/`catch` block?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, "IHM" means "UI" in my language. Thank I fixed.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, the catch do nothing, then `pingReply` remains null. Next `ProgressChanged` will manage this case.

Comment: Pro Tipp: If Exception swallowing is the intended thing to do, leave a comment like `// ignore exceptions: because <reasons>`. Any reader will trip over such an empty catch, otherwise. Probably yourself in two weeks, too.